# Can anyone help me figure out why this while loop won't work for the "Palindrome Number" LeetCode problem?

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        
        int reverse = 0;            
        int num;
        
        while (x!=0){
            
            num = x % 10;
            
            x /= 10;
            
            reverse = (reverse * 10) + num; 
            
        }
        
        if (reverse == x){                
            return true;
        }   
        else if (x < 0){
            return false;            
        }
        else if (reverse != x){
            return false;            
    }
}
```

I know the solution is to have while(x > reverse) but I don't know why that works and mine doesn't.

Comment: You must add an `else` clause with a return statement inside it (or just the return statement at the end of the method). Without it, the code won't compile.

Comment: Do you mean add an else statement within the while loop?

Comment: No, after the last `else if`.

Comment: I tried but it still didn't work. I'm not getting a compiler error anymore but it is returning false when true is expected

Comment: For what input it is giving false? Is there any input that gives the correct result?

Comment: for 121. I think anything that should return false will work, but for some reason it just won't return true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you're modifying the `x` parameter, and thus in the comparison `reverse == x`, `x` will be 0 and `reverse` the reversed number (i.e. always false, unless the input is 0). You can do something like that:

```java
class Solution {
    public static boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        // Create a new variable to modify instead of x
        int n = x;
        int reverse = 0;            
        int num;
        
        while (n!=0) {
            num = n % 10;
            n /= 10;
            reverse = (reverse * 10) + num;
        }
        
        if (reverse == x) return true;
        if (x < 0) return false;
        if (reverse != x) return false;
        return false;
    }
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isPalindrome(12));    // false
        System.out.println(isPalindrome(121));   // true
        System.out.println(isPalindrome(1111));  // true
    }
}
```

Comment: @PostChalone Glad to help! If my answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the big checkmark to select it as the accepted answer, so people answering can focus on older questions which still don't have answers.